# Set factor data with MANY levels a data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, character

I have an example `data.frame` `df` with factor and numeric data (see code below). In my real `data.frame`, column B is character, so I set it to be character. How can I change column B from "character" to "factor with 26 levels" (for each unique letter)?

```
 A=paste("a",1:200,sep="")
 B=sample(letters,200,replace=T)
 C=rnorm(200)
 df=data.frame(A,B,C)
 # Now column B is "factor with 26 levels"
 df$B <- lapply(df$B, as.character)
 # Now column B is "character"
 # How do I convert column B back to "factor with 26 levels"?
 # I tried df$B <- lapply(df$B, as.factor), but then column B is "factor with 1 levels"
```

I looked at posts like this:
[in R, how to set and retain custom levels in factor with different labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54850701/in-r-how-to-set-and-retain-custom-levels-in-factor-with-different-labels)
Which work fine if you only have several levels to set, but I have 26 levels.

I assume that there must be an easier fix?

Comment: Since you want to change only one column you don't need `lapply`, To change to character do `df$B <- as.character(df$B)`. To change to factor do `df$B <- as.factor(df$B)`

Comment: Wow, amazingly simple! Thank you so much! :)